# Android Dependencies - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: android, dependencies, google-play-services

I just updated my google play services lib with the newest one. There is no error in compiler but this NoClassDefFoundError appear in the logcat when i run the project. Before i update my google play service lib there is no problem, but i have to update my google play serviceslib to get Google Analytic class.

This is the logcat

```
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at com.dycode.ktb.KTBApp.onCreate(KTBApp.java:57)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-08 07:19:51.048: E/AndroidRuntime(1813):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And when I look at my dependecies , google-play-services_lib.jar just contains android.unusedStub.class

Thank you in advance

Comment: Google has modified the way you can import play services, you're no longer obliged to import everything (making the app exceeding the dex limit)
Take a look a this blog post :
http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html

Comment: @Tr4X can eclipse do that?

Comment: Did you try removing it from workspace, possibly re-downloading it and adding it again? Also try to clean the projects. And also, the class you are looking for is in a JAR file in the library project. So that JAR file should go with your project.

Comment: As juunas said, maybe cleaning your project will help. About Eclipse, I'm not sure if google has provided separated jars for submodules of the play service, but I don't think so. Migrate to Android Studio might worth the deal...

Comment: @Tr4X Thank you for your information, but because of some reason i have to finish this project in eclipse. and im thinking to use google analytic V3, do you think V3 is still work?

Comment: Yes it should work, but you might miss some features